# display required field warning as html

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to display the required field warning as php as shown in image while triggering submit button.Now It displayed message.Is it possible to do it? 
[image]

C#

```
<p class="field-wrapper required-field"> <label>Company Name</label><asp:TextBox ID="c_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator controltovalidate="c_name" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="invalid"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the easiest way to go should be the ValidatorCalloutExtender from Ajax Toolkit.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqTextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Data" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="rqValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="rqTextBox1" >                </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

working sample here: http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx

Comment: How to get  ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender from standard toolbar

Comment: how to install it.can you please guide me to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use html input tag:

```
<input id="c_name" type="text" name="c_name" placeholder="Company Name" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" />
```